# How to place a flat object orthogonal to camera, but not center of camera view

Tags: camera, orthographic

I am looking for a way to accurately place a flat object, in my case a watch, into the lower right corner of my camera view so it is exactly orthogonal to the camera.

The camera is looking at the default cube from above at an angle. If I use the camera position and angle to position the watch, it is accurately orthogonal as long as it is placed in the center of the camera view. But I need it to sit in one of the corners.

How can I make orthogonal to the camera?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you provide more information about what you want to do? Some pictures? Is the watch far from the camera or in front of it? Do you want the watch to be undeformed by the camera perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give your watch a Track to Object Constraint that tracks the Camera.
Now the watch always looks at the camera no matter where you move it.

[image: Track to Camera]

Comment: This does the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way, as I'm afraid using constraints will involve unwanted rotations.

[image]

Use the camera, the watch and an empty.

- At the begining place these objects without any rotation. The empty at the camera origin and the watch at the center of the camera.
- Parent the empty to the camera and parent the watch to the empty and below it
- Then go in camera view and rotate the empty in its X and Y axis to place the watch where you want

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I believe this would also work nicely, yet, I went with the answer above as it solved my problem more quickly.

Comment: Constraint will make the object (watch) rotate when camera rotates... though you did not want that.

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I did not phrase my question correctly. I am not looking to move the camera after the clock is set to its position. I will try to correct my initial post. Thank you for your help.